# How do I change values in a two dimensional array using .map()?

Tags: javascript

I have to convert this array into one that has `'even'` or `'odd'` depending on the item. I know that `.map()` can be nested into the solution but I also have to implement nested `for` loops in this solution.

I have used a nested `for` loop but I get only the first row with all the values `'odd`'.

```
var numbers = [
    [243, 12, 23, 12, 45, 45, 78, 66, 223, 3],
    [34, 2, 1, 553, 23, 4, 66, 23, 4, 55],
    [67, 56, 45, 553, 44, 55, 5, 428, 452, 3],
    [12, 31, 55, 445, 79, 44, 674, 224, 4, 21],
    [4, 2, 3, 52, 13, 51, 44, 1, 67, 5],
    [5, 65, 4, 5, 5, 6, 5, 43, 23, 4424],
    [74, 532, 6, 7, 35, 17, 89, 43, 43, 66],
    [53, 6, 89, 10, 23, 52, 111, 44, 109, 80],
    [67, 6, 53, 537, 2, 168, 16, 2, 1, 8],
    [76, 7, 9, 6, 3, 73, 77, 100, 56, 100]
];

// your code goes here
console.log(numbers.map(function(){
    for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
        for (var j = 0; j < numbers[i].length; j++){
            if (numbers[i][j] % 2 === 0){
                return "even";
            } else { 
                return "odd";
            }
        }
    }
}));
```

I get this error:

```
[ 'odd', 'odd', 'odd', 'odd', 'odd', 'odd', 'odd', 'odd', 'odd', 'odd' ]
```

I implemented a solution:

```
for (row = 0; row < numbers.length; row++){
    for (c = 0; c < numbers[row].length; c++){
        return numbers[row][c] % 2 ? "even" : "odd"; 
    }
}

console.log(numbers);
```

No output is displayed on the console.

Comment: it's not an error, just how .map() works, for 2d array you want to use nested .map()

Comment: I added an if statement to select 'even' or 'odd'.

Comment: @EmmanuelAni - The problem with your code is that you're looping through `numbers` in your callback, and doing a `return` on the first iteration. That stops the loop from continuing by exiting from the callback immediately. So you just see the result for `numbers[0][0]` in each position.

Comment: What do you want the output to be?

Comment: A nested array with corresponding 'even' and 'odd' values. @T.J.Crowder

Comment: @T.J.Crowder what about the `row++` and `c++` parts of the for loops?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To process two nested array you need two nested `map` calls:

```
console.log(numbers.map(row =>
    row.map(element =>
        element%2 ? "odd" : "even"
    )
));
```

`.map` iterates over the contents of an array, therefore if you use it on an array of arrays, it'll pass the inner array on every iteration (`row`). Then we can call `.map` on that again, and access the inner arrays values from inside the provided callback (`element`). That callback then evaluates to "even" or "odd", therefore `row.map(...)` evaluates to an array of these strings, and `numbers.map(...)` evaluates to an array of arrays.

Comment: @Jonas - Great stuff!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder naa ... could be done better with a step-by-step walkthrough, but it's not my answer and I'm not in the mood to spend more time on this ... might encourage the answerer to take it further though ...

Comment: @JonasWilms: I think your edit is indeed ok and detailed enough. Of course it will require some work to be understood but everything is there. I'd have extended it but I didn't notice the comment (I don't agree with it, but probably my code was a bit too cryptic if 4 upvoted the comment).

Comment: Well the OP did not use arrow functions yet and seems to be slightly confused about for loops / `.map` ... not sure if he would've understood your answer without an explanation

Comment: @EmmanuelAni: there was typo on the first original posting, I fixed it quickly after and now it's correct.

Comment: Guys please take another look at the question. I added a solution I implemented. I have to use nested `for` loops to do this, though.

Comment: @EmmanuelAni - Then why does the question title **specifically** say *"...using .map()"*?

Comment: Wrong title, I guess? I was of the impression that `.map()` would do the trick. My console shows that not all its changed values are correct. Please check. @T.J.Crowder

Comment: @EmmanuelAni: you need first to understand clearly what is a loop and what `return` means

Comment: is `element%2` supposed to be `odd`? @6502

Comment: @EmmanuelAni: `element % 2` (when `element` is an integer number) will be 1 for odd numbers and 0 for even numbers. `0` is "falsy" and `1` is "truthy" in Javascript... so in this specific case `number%2 ? "odd" : "even"` is the same as `number%2 === 1 ? "odd" : "even"`.

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of `.map` is that you don't have to iterate through the array using `for` loops. The `function()` will get called once for each member of the array upon which `map` is called.

`numbers` is an array of arrays. You will therefore need to run `map` on each of the inner ararys, thus:

```
numbers.map(function(arr) { return arr.map(function(n) { return num%2?"odd":"even"; }) ; });
```

Answer (score 1):

How do we check if the numbers are odd or even? We divide them by 2. If their remainder is 0 then they are even.

1. Map the `numbers` array and we will have all the arrays of numbers inside them
2. Map the array's inside the `numbers` array. So we have numbers inside the arrays. So then we can check if the remainder is 0. If it is then return "even" else return "odd".

`.map` will give us all the arrays inside the numbers array and guess what? The things inside the numbers array are also arrays! So we have to use two maps to get to the numbers.

```js
var numbers = [
    [243, 12, 23, 12, 45, 45, 78, 66, 223, 3],
    [34, 2, 1, 553, 23, 4, 66, 23, 4, 55],
    [67, 56, 45, 553, 44, 55, 5, 428, 452, 3],
    [12, 31, 55, 445, 79, 44, 674, 224, 4, 21],
    [4, 2, 3, 52, 13, 51, 44, 1, 67, 5],
    [5, 65, 4, 5, 5, 6, 5, 43, 23, 4424],
    [74, 532, 6, 7, 35, 17, 89, 43, 43, 66],
    [53, 6, 89, 10, 23, 52, 111, 44, 109, 80],
    [67, 6, 53, 537, 2, 168, 16, 2, 1, 8],
    [76, 7, 9, 6, 3, 73, 77, 100, 56, 100]
];
let answers = numbers.map(numArray => { // first array
    return numArray.map(numbers => { // the arrays of numbers inside the numbers array. Also return what we get from this map
        if (numbers % 2 == 0){ // if the remainder is 0 when divided by 2
            return "even"; // the number is even
        }else{
          return "odd"; // else it is odd
        }
    });
});
console.log(answers) // log the answer.
```

Answer (score 0):

About your code:

```
console.log(numbers.map(function(){
    for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){ // <-- first error here (1)
        for (var j = 0; j < numbers[i].length; j++){
            if (numbers[i][j] % 2 === 0){
                return "even"; // <-- second error here (2)
            } else { 
                return "odd";
            }
        }
    }
}));
```

There are two points that you need to understand:

Error #1: (see (1) above) - You are looping the same array inside `map`. Said prototype (map) already loops the array, so you are actually using map for no reason, in that context.

Error #2: (see (2) above) - You are using `return` inside the `map` callback. This is not technically wrong, it's just that in your context, you are not returning the value of the **nested arrays value**, but you are returning the value of the **main array looped item**, which will return an array of **10** strings in your case, while you want to return an **array of string arrays**, hence why you should use a nested map approach (see below):

Assuming you want to keep the same format for the output array, you may want to use two nested `map`, because the first one will iterate the `numbers` array, and the nested one will iterate the nested arrays.

Further explanations are directly in the code below.

```js
var numbers = [ // <-- first map iterates at this level.
    [243, 12, 23, 12, 45, 45, 78, 66, 223, 3],
//  ^     ^-^-------------------------------^--- nested map (numberSet.map) argument example (12)
//  |---------------------------------------|- numberSet map argument example ([..])
    [34, 2, 1, 553, 23, 4, 66, 23, 4, 55],
    [67, 56, 45, 553, 44, 55, 5, 428, 452, 3],
    [12, 31, 55, 445, 79, 44, 674, 224, 4, 21],
    [4, 2, 3, 52, 13, 51, 44, 1, 67, 5],
    [5, 65, 4, 5, 5, 6, 5, 43, 23, 4424],
    [74, 532, 6, 7, 35, 17, 89, 43, 43, 66],
    [53, 6, 89, 10, 23, 52, 111, 44, 109, 80],
    [67, 6, 53, 537, 2, 168, 16, 2, 1, 8],
    [76, 7, 9, 6, 3, 73, 77, 100, 56, 100]
];

var res = numbers.map(numbersSet => { // <-- first `map` iterates over the ARRAYS inside `numbers`.
  // Here, numbersSet is an array of numbers, so in the first iteration it will be [243, 12, 23, 12, 45, 45, 78, 66, 223, 3], in the second iteration it will be [34, 2, 1, 553, 23, 4, 66, 23, 4, 55] and so on.
  return numbersSet.map(n => n % 2 === 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'); // <-- the second map loop each item of the inner array (so, of the numberSet), and returns even or odd to EACH of the items.
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use `.flat()` to create an array with all the sub-arrays that you have and then `.map()` over each element and see if it's even or odd.

```js
let numbers = [
    [243, 12, 23, 12, 45, 45, 78, 66, 223, 3],
    [34, 2, 1, 553, 23, 4, 66, 23, 4, 55],
    [67, 56, 45, 553, 44, 55, 5, 428, 452, 3],
    [12, 31, 55, 445, 79, 44, 674, 224, 4, 21],
    [4, 2, 3, 52, 13, 51, 44, 1, 67, 5],
    [5, 65, 4, 5, 5, 6, 5, 43, 23, 4424],
    [74, 532, 6, 7, 35, 17, 89, 43, 43, 66],
    [53, 6, 89, 10, 23, 52, 111, 44, 109, 80],
    [67, 6, 53, 537, 2, 168, 16, 2, 1, 8],
    [76, 7, 9, 6, 3, 73, 77, 100, 56, 100]
];

const myNumbers = numbers.flat().map(number => number & 2 ? 'odd' : 'even')

console.log(myNumbers)
```

Comment: This mutilates the shape of the array.

Comment: @user234461 actually op never specified what the output should look like.

Comment: @ChrisLi in that case, why not just `return "garbage";`?

Comment: @user234461 if you think that's what op wants you can write that as an answer, you shouldn't just go around downvoting based on something you don't know.

Answer (score -4):

The console accepted this, although no code was output:

```
for (row = 0; row < numbers.length; row++){
    for (c = 0; c < numbers[row].length; c++){
        return numbers[row][c] % 2 ? "even" : "odd"; 
    }
}

console.log(numbers);
```

Comment: In case you're wondering why you're being downvoted, here's my guess: The question asked to use `.map`, and using map is not an inappropriate solution, so this answer doesn't really answer the question. Also, people tend to appreciate more explanation in an answer, not just a code snippet. For example, you could explain where OP has gone wrong (i.e. explain that `numbers` is an array of arrays), or explain why you prefer `for` loops.